# How to do a while loop for a MySQL query in Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, while-loop

I am currently trying to transform a php code into Node.js using Typescript & Express.

In a script, I am generating a random 6-digit code before querying the database to verify that the code doesn't exist, otherwise I generate a new one.

Here's the original PHP code :

```
    $code = generate_random_int(); // Generate a random code

    $existing_codes = exec_sql($db,"SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code = $code;"); // Check if the generated code already exists in the database

    while(!empty($existing_codes)){ // While there is (at least) 1 occurence in the DB for the generated code

        $code = generate_random_int(); // Generate a new random code

        $existing_codes = exec_sql($db,"SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code = $code;"); // Update the check for the newly generated code.

        // If an occurence is found, the while loop will be reiterated. Otherwise, the while loop will end with the last generated code.
    }
```

However, Node.js MySQL library only allows callbacks, because the function is asynchronous, which prevent the behavior I've illustrated above.

I have looked here and there on the internet and haven't found any way to reproduce this behavior in Node.js, so that's why I'm writing here :)

I thought about using for loops with db.query calls in them with no success, same with while syntaxes and an updated boolean.
Here's my latest (unsuccessful) attempt :

```
        let code = generateRandomInt()

        // query is a simplified function for db.query() from MySQL
        query(`SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code = ${code};`, result => {
            if (result === []) {
                res.send(String(code))
                return
            } else {
                code = generateRandomInt()
                // While loop creating a new SQL statement for the new code and regenerating it until the response is []
            }
        })

        res.send(String(code))
```

Thanks a lot by advance for your help :)

PS : I'm a newbie to Express and I am not that used to post on StackOverflow, so please don't hesitate to tell me if I did something wrong or if you need any complementary information

Comment: Use the Promise version of `node-mysql`. Then you can use `await` in a loop.

Comment: If you just want to pick an entry, `SELECT code FROM codes where code >= ?` a way to do this without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. Once you have an array of existing codes, use a loop to find an unused one:

```
...
const go = async () => {
  const existingCodes = await getExistingCodes();  // your function that returns a list 
                                                   // of existing codes; return a Promise
  // find an unused code
  let code = generateRandomInt();
  while (existingCodes.indexOf(code) !== -1) {
    code = generateRandomInt();
  }

  // use your new code
  console.log(`new code is: ${code}`);
};
go();
```